# Get values from stored procedure to class in c# using linqToSql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

This is my c# code that will take server date from database using Stored procedure. I am using linq to fetch the value from stored procedure. On data context, while executing the stored procedure, date and time is shown. But when I keep the code in class, return value is 0.Can anyone help me. This is my code,

```
public class NetworkTime
{
       CheckoutDataContext DataContext = new CheckoutDataContext();
       public DateTime GetDateTimeFromServer()
       {
             var  date = DataContext.SPGetDate().ReturnValue;
             return Convert.ToDateTime(date);
       }
}
```

SPGetDate is the name of stored procedure. Can anyone tell how can I get date and time!!!

Comment: what's the value of date?

Comment: it returns 0 as value of date.

Comment: i think you dont have to use spname.returnvalue. just try without it

Comment: on removing .returnvalue, an error "Unable to cast object of type 'SingleResult`1[SPGetDateResult]' to type 'System.IConvertible'." is shown..

Comment: how DataContext.SPGetDate().FirstOrDefault()

Comment: i had also tried to use .FirstOrDefault() but this property is not avaliable for DataContext.SPGetDate()...

Comment: ya.. this way but for DataContext.SPGetDate() only properties like returnvalue, getenumerate are shown..

Comment: can i see sp definition in sql server

Comment: USE [EmployeeCheckout]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SPGetDate]    Script Date: 05/12/2014 04:56:07 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create procedure [dbo].[SPGetDate]
as 
Begin
select GETDATE()
end
GO

Comment: You're only missing a `using System.Linq`.

Comment: thanks gert. now its working. thought system.data.linq would work..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to retrieve database current date and time. I suggest instead of wrapping sqlserver getdate() in a sp I suggest you do the following:

```
DataClasses1DataContext DataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    var result = DataContext.ExecuteQuery<DateTime>("SELECT GETDATE()").First();
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: again, same problem. I tried this:                               public DateTime GetDate()
  {
    return DataContext.ExecuteQuery<DateTime>("SELECT GETDATE()").First();
  }                                                                    but .First() is not taken. It says "Error 32 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
"